# For loop to fill if statement parameters

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

i am working with a basic if statement such as

```
if(b==0 || b==2)
{
    //do something
}
```

The problem is that when in use b may be equal to more than 2 integers...or less. I have tried writing.

```
if(
   /* for loop to check b against an ArrayList of ints adding || if iteration is anything but the ArrayLists size - 1 */
){
   //do something
}
```

Eclipse obviously won't let me do this. is there a way to work with possible different numbers of b==0 || b==2 || b==... ?

**edit

the if statement is already inside a for loop which iterates b

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you could try an if inside a for loop rather than the other way around.

Comment: Why don't you add the acceptable numbers to a List<Integer> and then do a acceptableNumbers.contains(b)?

Comment: How can `b` be equal to more than 2 integers? Doesn't represent a single integer?

Comment: `b may be equal to more than 2 integers` ,Sorry. Not possible.

Comment: I have written a metronome which writes synthetic sound (either one of two sounds) to an array and written to an AudioTrack. the sound is decided by which beat of the bar we are on. (so for musical groupings this could be just 1...or 1, 3, and 5)...

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that the if statement is already inside a for loop which iterates b

Comment: i need to head to work so dont have time to try but im sure that the answer provided by keppil will work. I will accept when i can in 4 minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a list of all integers you want to check against, and use `contains()`;

```
List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(0, 2, 5, 7);
if (values.contains(b)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `HashSet`? Wouldn't the lookup be `O(1)` then instead of `O(n)`?

Comment: @crush: I don't think the added complexity warrants it here, but sure, you could use a `HashSet` instead to improve performance.

Comment: Is it really more complex?

Comment: @crush: It is not as clear as this. Premature optimization of trivial matters like this is seldom a good idea IMO, but opinions may vary.

Comment: I'd disagree. It's not premature optimization when the code hasn't even been written yet. Premature optimization would be obsessing over the performance of bit of code you already wrote. If you already know that one technique is the right tool for the job, then you have no excuse for not using it. I'm not sure why you are so staunch on defending your use of a List as a look-up table. Basically, if there are more than 6 items in the collection, then HashSet is the tool for the job.